# Can someone explain why this happen?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dom, equation-solving

```
const chessBoard = document.querySelector("#board");
let aSwitch = true; // define a switch to create black & white square
let increment = 1; // will be use to determine the row of the board

for (let i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
  let square = document.createElement("div");
  square.classList.add("square");

  if (aSwitch === true) {
    square.classList.add("white");
    aSwitch = false;
   } else {
        square.classList.add("black");
    aSwitch = true;
  }

  if (i === 7 * increment) {
    increment++;
   aSwitch = !aSwitch;
  } // ensure that the next row will follow a checkered pattern
  chessBoard.append(square);
}
```

output:

[image: chessboard with the equation 8 * increment - 1]

however if i change the sequence to `i === 8 * increment`, the output is:

[image: chessboard with the equation 8 * increment]

Please help me understand this phenomenon since i am very dummb and confused, thanks alot!

I did try using the internet, and best i came up with was that the square was in a 0-index sequence, but when i try using the equation `7 * increment`, the output was also wrong:

[image: chessboard with equation 7 * increment]

Comment: The index of the last square in the current row should be `8 * increment - 1`.

Comment: The code will work if you put your check before adding the class to the square: https://jsfiddle.net/fu5yht3m/

Comment: Please read [ask], starting with the part about "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem".

Answer (score 1):

Another way of solving it is by nesting loops. An outer one for rows, and an inner one for columns. You can then use this formula to get the [remainder (%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) of a division by 2 to determine if the sum is even or odd:

```
(col + row) % 2
```

This will work with any size board. Demo:

```js
const chessBoard = document.querySelector("#board");
const boardSize = 8;
// Set the width of the board accordingly
document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--boardsize', boardSize);

for (let row = 0; row < boardSize; row++) {
  for (let col = 0; col < boardSize; col++) {
    const color = (col + row) % 2 ? 'black' : 'white';
    addSquare(color);
  }
}

function addSquare(color) {
  const square = document.createElement("div");
  square.classList.add("square", color);
  chessBoard.append(square);
}
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>                                                                                                       <style>:root{--boardsize: 8}#board{width:calc(var(--boardsize) * 20px);border:1px solid #000;line-height:0}.square{width:20px;height:20px;display:inline-block}.black{background:#000}</style>
```

Comment: This. So much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not correct:

`7 * increment` will give 7, 14, 21, ... So you are checking the 8th square, but then the 15th, the 22nd and so on.

`8 * increment` will give 8, 16, 24, ... Again. this is not what you want.

You need to use the remainder operator `%`: the expression `i % 8 === 7` will be true at the 8th, 16th, 24th, ... square.